# Django not saving the data to database

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a very basic knowledge of Django and having come across a problem, it has rendered me totally confused.

I am trying to construct a 3D plotter. Everything is rendering properly but when I click **Submit**, it never saves to the database except the specified **default value** that I have provided.

My **models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Value(models.Model):
    eq_input = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='x**2 + y**2')
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Magma')
```

My **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Value

class ViewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Equation = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label='Equation')
    Color = forms.CharField(max_length=20,label='Color')
    class Meta:
        model = Value
        fields = {
            'Equation',
            'Color'
         }
```

My **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Value
from .forms import ViewForm

def home_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ViewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
       form = ViewForm()
     context = {
           'form': form
        }
   return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

My **home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>3D Graph Plotter</title>
</head>
<body>
     <center><h1>This is a 3D plotter</h1></center>
     <center>
     <form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
         {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="Save" />
        </form>
   </center>
  </body>
  </html>
```

and my **urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from equation.views import eq, home_view

urlpatterns = [
          path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
          path('', home_view, name='hv')
     ]
```

Can you point out the problem to me?

Comment: Because you don't have fields named `Equation` or `Color` in your model. Why did you expect Django to be able to map `Equation` to `eq_input`?

Comment: @Selcuk My bad! I didn't know that they had to be same 'cause I had to rewrite them again in forms, so I thought it can be anything. I had a gut feeling that something was wrong there. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You don't have to rewrite them, you just pick the ones you want in your form from your model.

Answer (score 0):

Put `{{ form.errors }} {{ form.non_field_errors }}` in your `home.html` and see if there are any errors in the data that the temp posts to the view. Maybe the data is not valid, too common password or something else.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>3D Graph Plotter</title>
</head>
<body>
     <center><h1>This is a 3D plotter</h1></center>
     <center>
    <form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
         {{ form.as_p }}
         {{ form.errors }}
         {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <input type="submit" name="Save" />
        </form>
   </center>
  </body>
  </html>
```